# Django mysql setup error on mac os

Tags: python, django, macos

]mitwas-MacBook-Air:mytestsite Mitwa$ pip3 install MYSQL-python
Collecting MYSQL-python

Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/9l/9zjr811503367lfnybnyqlqc0000gn/T/pip-build-fk08ytxi/MYSQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
```

from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/private/var/folders/9l/9zjr811503367lfnybnyqlqc0000gn/T/pip-build-fk08ytxi/MYSQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in 
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/9l/9zjr811503367lfnybnyqlqc0000gn/T/pip-build-fk08ytxi/MYSQL-python/

I am getting this error while setting up Django MYSQL for python. Anyone have idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

`MYSQL-python` is not compatible with Python 3. Install mysqlclient instead.

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```